# How can I slideToggle an input and autofocus at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to slideToggle a hidden div onClick and also autofocus on the input.

I've tried this and I've also tried just $( ".search-input" ).focus(); and $(this).find('input[type="text"]').focus(); neither seem to work.

What am I missing here...?

```
$( ".search" ).click(function() {
  $( ".search-input" ).slideToggle();
  $(this).find('input[type="text"]').focus();
});
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/odu7ckzh/

Any suggestions are welcome :) Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just chain `.focus()` to the `.slideToggle()`

```
$( ".search" ).click(function() {
  $( ".search-input" ).slideToggle().focus();
});
```